# No audio: upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04, audio-jack, intel-nuc

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 to find that my hdmi audio is no longer working.

**System details:**

Device: Intel NUC9VXQNX

Processor: Intel® Xeon(R) E-2286M CPU @ 2.40GHz × 16

Kernal: 5.4.0-54-generic

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio

00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [8086:a348] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [8086:2088]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

$ lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel

snd_hda_intel          53248  4
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core           90112  8 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_pcm               106496  8 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd                    90112  19 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi


$ cat /proc/asound/card0/pcm0c/info

card: 0
device: 0
subdevice: 0
stream: CAPTURE
id: ALC256 Analog
name: ALC256 Analog
subname: subdevice #0
class: 0
subclass: 0
subdevices_count: 1
subdevices_avail: 1
```

Solutions attempted:

I have tried modifying the /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf snd-hda-intel model parameter as follows and neither of these solutions have worked:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
options snd-hda-intel model=laptop-amic
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

Any help is much appreciated, as I have been working without sound for a few weeks now...

Answer (score 0):

What is your active profile for your sound device? You may check that with the following command:

```
pacmd list-cards
```

The `active profile` is what will show for both inputs and outputs within Ubuntu Settings/Sound. If you have `active profile: <off>`, this would explain why you are not seeing it.

Use the index number shown in that output to set your active profile by modifying:

```
/etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Here is an example:

```bsh
### Make some devices default
set-default-sink 2  output:hdmi-stereo
set-default-source 2
```

where the `2` above is the index number shown for the device, and `output:hdmi-stereo` is the profile name.